# Distance Math in JavaScript and Implementing it in loop?

Tags: javascript, loops, maps, distance

I'm having the difficulties with calculating distance between several points on the map:

I have an array of coordinats where the first coord ["30.327547", "59.919676"] is the begining of the trip and other are pit stops:

```
var J = [
    ["30.327547", "59.919676"],
    ["29.84964", "58.737619"],
    ["28.250252", "57.785994"],
    ["30.098912", "55.175885"],
    ["30.37357", "54.503783"],
    ["27.572056", "53.898325"],
    ["26.000193", "53.11856"]
```

];

Next, to make the Geopoints on the map from this coords I shoul use special Yandex Maps API function YMaps.Geopoint:

```
var a=new YMaps.GeoPoint(30.327547,59.919676);
var b=new YMaps.GeoPoint(29.84964,58.737619);
var c=new YMaps.GeoPoint(28.250252,57.785994);
var d=new YMaps.GeoPoint(30.098912,55.175885);
var e=new YMaps.GeoPoint(30.37357,54.503783);
var f=new YMaps.GeoPoint(27.572056,53.898325);
var g=new YMaps.GeoPoint(26.000193,53.11856);
```

Finally, to calculate distances between points i use another API function "point1.distance(point2)":

```
var d1=a.distance(b);        //distance1
var d2=a.distance(b)+b.distance(c);    //distance2
var d3=a.distance(b)+b.distance(c)+c.distance(d);  //distance3
var d4=a.distance(b)+b.distance(c)+c.distance(d)+d.distance(e);   //distance4
var d5=a.distance(b)+b.distance(c)+c.distance(d)+d.distance(e)+e.distance(f);   //distance5
var d6=a.distance(b)+b.distance(c)+c.distance(d)+d.distance(e)+e.distance(f)+f.distance(g);   //distance6
```

This works pretty well (I also convert each result to format (result km) ) and the result is:

```
    console.log(YMaps.humanDistance(d1));console.log(YMaps.humanDistance(d2));console.log(YMaps.humanDistance(d3));
    console.log(YMaps.humanDistance(d4));console.log(YMaps.humanDistance(d5));console.log(YMaps.humanDistance(d6));

//{"Point1":"134 km.","Point2":"275 km.","Point3":"586 km.","Point4":"663 km.","Point5":"857 km.","Point6":"992 km."}
```

What I actually want to make this operations inside a loop:

```
for(var i=0;i<J.length;i++){

    // Iteratting through the array of points of J and creating Geoobjects on the map, dynamically putting them into public variables "temp_*"
    window["temp_" + i]=new YMaps.GeoPoint(J[i][0],J[i][1]);

    //next point
    var next=i+1;
    //master point (the begin of trip)
    var master=window["temp_0"];


    //calculating the distance between the master point and actual [i] point in the loop
    var formula=master.distance(window["temp_"+i]);

    // calculating the distance between the actual [i] point and the next in the loop
    var formula2=window["temp_" + i].distance(window["temp_"+next]);


    //summing and converting into human format and dinamically putting them into variables "result_*"
    window["result_"+i]=YMaps.humanDistance(formula+formula2);

    //logging the results
    console.log(YMaps.humanDistance(window["result_"+i]));
    }
```

This loop works but returns wrong results. Could anybody advice what is wrong in the loop?
I guess that probably i need to use another loop in this loop that woul return  the summ of other points so many times as neccessary (requires).
 Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `J` variable is a two dimensional array of strings as you declared it and from what I can see the `YMaps.GeoPoint` function expects a number. So try parsing:

```
window['temp_' + i] = new YMaps.GeoPoint(
    parseFloat(J[i][0]), 
    parseFloat(J[i][1])
);
```

---

UPDATE:

Here's what's wrong with your code:

```
var formula=master.distance(window["temp_"+i]);
var formula2=window["temp_" + i].distance(window["temp_"+next]);
window["result_"+i]=YMaps.humanDistance(formula+formula2);
```

On each iteration you redeclare the `formula2` variable and when you calculate the human distance between the current points. You need to accumulate the sum, so declare the variable outside the loop and add to it inside:

```
var sum = 0;
for(var i = 0; i < J.length - 1; i++) {
    var p1 = new YMaps.GeoPoint(J[i][0], J[i][1]);
    var p2 = new YMaps.GeoPoint(J[i + 1][0], J[i + 1][1]);
    sum += p1.distance(p2);
    console.log(YMaps.humanDistance(sum);
}
```

Notice that the loop ends at `J.length - 1`: ex. for 7 points you have 6 distances.

Comment: It parses well without using parseFloat, but my difficult is to implement this dependence:

var d1=a.distance(b);        //distance1
var d2=a.distance(b)+b.distance(c);    //distance2
var d3=a.distance(b)+b.distance(c)+c.distance(d); ...

where with each calculation next points adds

Comment: thanks. and how could i do it without using dynamic variables window["temp_"+i] outside the loop?